Laravel: Conditional Binding of Interfaces in Service Provider Not Working as Expected
I'm working with Laravel (version 11) and trying to conditionally bind an interface (DashboardStrategy) to different concrete implementations (DashboardWebService and DashboardApiService) depending on which controller is being resolved (DashboardWebController or DashboardApiController).
Problem:
I'm encountering the following error:
Target [App\Services\Dashboard\DashboardStrategy] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardWebController].

I've set up my AppServiceProvider as follows:
public function boot(): void
{
    // Inject DashboardApiService for DashboardStrategy when resolving DashboardApiController
    $this->app->when(DashboardApiController::class)
        ->needs(DashboardStrategy::class)
        ->give(DashboardApiService::class);

    // Inject DashboardWebService for DashboardStrategy when resolving DashboardWebController
    $this->app->when(DashboardWebController::class)
        ->needs(DashboardStrategy::class)
        ->give(DashboardWebService::class);
}

public function register(): void
{
    $this->app->singleton(DashboardApiService::class, function (Application $app) {
        return new DashboardApiService($app->make(ImageService::class));
    });

    $this->app->singleton(DashboardWebService::class, function (Application $app) {
        return new DashboardWebService($app->make(ImageService::class));
    });
}

Despite this setup, Laravel still throws the error mentioned above.
What I've Tried:

Simplified the binding as follows, and this works:
$this->app->singleton(DashboardStrategy::class, DashboardApiService::class);

However, this forces both controllers to use the same service, which I want to avoid.

Cleared all caches:
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled


Double-checked the constructor in DashboardServiceManager to ensure it’s expecting a DashboardStrategy:
public function __construct(DashboardStrategy $dashboardStrategy)
{
    $this->dashboardStrategy = $dashboardStrategy;
}



Question:
How can I correctly set up the conditional binding so that DashboardWebService is injected when resolving DashboardWebController, and DashboardApiService is injected when resolving DashboardApiController?
Is there a better approach to handle this kind of situation in Laravel, or am I missing something in my current implementation?

Bind the DashboardStrategy interface to a concrete class,do this:
``` on `register()`

put 1st the bind() and then the singleton().

App\Services\Dashboard\DashboardServiceManager::__construct(): Argument #1 ($dashboardStrategy) must be of type App\Services\Dashboard\DashboardStrategy, string given, called in /Users/amirhossein/Documents/web programing/Projects/php-Laravel/ekkaShop/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php on line 33

what is the code in line 33?

$app->make(DashboardStrategy::class),

this wasn't in AppServiceProvider in the question...

I think the give() expects an instance so you can try this format since you already declared the singletons
public function boot(): void
{
    // Inject DashboardApiService for DashboardStrategy when resolving DashboardApiController
    $this->app->when(DashboardApiController::class)
        ->needs(DashboardStrategy::class)
        ->give(app(DashboardApiService::class));

    // Inject DashboardWebService for DashboardStrategy when resolving DashboardWebController
    $this->app->when(DashboardWebController::class)
        ->needs(DashboardStrategy::class)
        ->give(app(DashboardWebService::class));
}


I still have the error Target [App\Services\Dashboard\DashboardStrategy] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardWebController, 0000000000000009b00000000000000000].

@AmirHossein just a dump question. did you make sure you implemented DashboardStrategy in DashboardWebService ?

yes.
`<?php
namespace App\Services\Dashboard;
use App\Services\ImageService;
class DashboardWebService implements DashboardStrategy
{
function __construct(
protected ImageService  $imageService,
)
{
}`
